How to use QtGui.QFont in matplotlib for font family
I add QFontComboBox in my pyQt6 application, and I want to select a font family as the matplotlib font family, with the font family, I can set the matplotlib title and label font. But when I select a font in QFontComboBox, it raise an error: findfont: Font family 'Microsoft YaHei UI' not found.
But I have added the font to matplotlib font/ttf directory, How can I set the font correctly?
